# How to cut into an object that has a sub surface modifer with out changing the overall shape

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am trying to model Hornet from Hollow Knight, and I am not sure how to make the eyes.
How would you suggest I make holes in the object for the eyes without affecting the shape of the rest of the object.
[image: My object in edit mode]

Comment: You could duplicate the object to make a back up model, apply the subsurface, then use spheres to boolean eye holes. You might need to add a second subsurf after that.

Comment: I wouldnt use boolean at all, Its hard to keep modeling with that, you have to do a lot of repairing. You try to keep your model clean and simple and then you use booleans? No no no.Just delete some polygons and shape them to look like circles. The subdivision modifier helps. Then extrude inside. Watch any face modeling on youtube, no one will ever use a booleans for face modeling.
Also, with model like this, use mirror, so you dont have to care about the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Select these vertices and delete them, it will make 2 holes:

[image]

Select the border edge loop:

[image]

Extrude and scale down, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to round the selection, then give it the shape of the eyes:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that the subdivision surface modifer actually made that the object, srry Im new to blender. Thx

Comment: oh ok so in that case apply the modifier, then you'll give a second one to have a smooth shape